# How to break a line? (and safari mobile issue)

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-safari

I'm very confused about how to break lines. There is `word-wrap: break-word` and `word-break: break-all`. Note sure which one is the correct method, I don't care if the word will be cut in the middle. So I actually have 3 questions:

1. Which one is the correct way to do it
2. What the difference between word-break and word-wrap
3. Why safari don't work neither with `word-wrap: break-word` or `word-break: break-all`, but with the non-standard `word-break: break-word`

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not an expert, but I believe that `word-wrap: break-word` and `word-break: break-word` are the same thing.

They both differ from `word-break: break-all` in that they will try to break words in places that make sense (e.g. when there's a dash in the word) UNLESS the word spreads the entire width of the element, then it will chop the word at the last possible character.

`word-break: break-all`, on the other hand, will break everything at the last possible character when it reaches the width of the element.

So, which one you use depends on which effect you want.  If you really don't care if words are broken in the middle, `word-break: break-all` will be fine.  I have personally only ever used `word-wrap: break-word`, and I'm pretty sure that's the more conventional one.

I can't answer your safari question.  All browsers are just different in how they handle css, and sometimes (annoyingly) you just have to work around it as a developer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `word-break:break-all` is for East Asian languages with typesetting rules that allow line breaks very liberally. In contrast, `word-wrap: break-word` is for emergency breaks, for use when a word must be broken even though it does not contain permissible break points.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think about connotations for different languages.  Thanks for clearing that up. +1